# When exactly are the kernels initialized in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm using the Keras functional API, and I would like to know: when exactly are the kernels initialized? Is it during the creation of the layer, like in

```
x = Dense(32, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(x)
```

or is it during the compilation of the model? e.g.

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

I guess it's not during `model.fit(...)` or I wouldn't be able to fine-tune a pre-trained model, because the previous weights would be lost. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `Layer` superclass defines the method `build(input_shape)` that all derived classes that have weights, such as `Dense` and `Conv2D`,  must implement. In the method, among other things, the weight variables are created and initialized. This `build` is actually called by the `Layer`'s method `__call__`, which is the one called in the line

```
x = Dense(32, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(x)
```

right after the constructor, `__init__`.

Reference: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py